# Is there a html reporter plugin for JUnit, like ReportNG for TestNG?

Tags: html, plugins, junit, testng, reportng

ReportNG is a nice Html Reporter plugin for TestNG. I'm searching for an equivalent Version when using JUnit.
Does anyone knows some useful plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a html reporter for JUnit. However, if you're using maven or ant there are.

For maven, look at [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) (specifically [maven-surefire-report-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/))

For ant, look at the [JUnit Report task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html).